# How does JavaScript deals with value which is unknown?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am new to JavaScript and reading a [book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html) and in recursive chapter, there is an example as follow

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target)
      return history;
    else if (current > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(current + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(current * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
 *return find(1, "1"); // when will this run?
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
// → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

I am unable to understand how does JavaScript will run these causes as it expects a value of `current` in all three `if` cases? But the author is just running the outside of function which takes `target` as an argument, not the `current`. Does it take value of current and history from

```
return find(1,"1")
```

like in hoisting?

Comment: Immediately after defining `find` you call it with two arguments, `1` (`current`) and `"1"` (`history`). This isn't hoisting, you're literally passing them in.

Comment: without `return find(1, "1");` nothing much would happen. This inner function would not be called. It is the first call, and has two arguments. Nothing much to it.

Answer (score 1):

`current` and `history` are the names given to parameters on the `fund` function, not the `findSolution` function.

So yes, it will get those values when `find(1, "1")` is used to call that function (and then later, when `find(current * 5, …)` and `find(current + 3, …)` are called).

---

This is not, in any way, like or related to hoisting.

Answer (score 0):

`find` is just a nested function inside `findSolution`.`find` requires 2 parameters given by the `return find(1, "1")`.

That statement will run everytime you call `findSolution`, since `find` is just defined and you'll obviously have to call it.

Note that the `target` is a parameter of `findSolution` but can also be used in the nested functions of that method.

Comment: Thanks, one thing to ask why find call the second || and not the first one? or maybe which one returns and why as there is no comparison of >